# Fire Event Immediately if Checkbox is Checked, Calling Server-Side PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

These are my checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" onclick="check(this)">Batas Wilayah</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" onclick="check(this)">Lokasi Masjid</input><br>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    function check() {
        if ($('cb1').is(":checked")) {
            $.getScript("batas.php");
        } elseif ($('cb2').is(":checked")) {
            $.getScript("daftar.php");
        }
    }
```

When `cb1` or `cb2` are checked, I want to immediately call a server-side PHP script with the form data. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: the codes dont look like php, more like javascript/jquery

Comment: please demonstrated php code is correct! because I do not quite understand. so that when the checkbox is checked, will lead to a page that is intended.

Comment: You want to load a new page? Why are you using checkboxes and JavaScript? Just use a regular submit button.

Comment: That's the problem. This about giving event on the checkbox without submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.getScript is specifically for loading javascript. In theory it should still work fine but using a AJAX jQuery.get request is worth a shot.

```
$.get("batas.php", function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

In the above code `data` is the data returned from the php script.